# AvalonEdit Change Syntax Highlighting in Code

Tags: c#, wpf, syntax-highlighting, text-editor, avalonedit

I want to change the Syntax Highlighting of AvalonEdit in my Code.

XAML:

```
 <avalonEdit:TextEditor Name="textEditor" SyntaxHighlighting="{Binding syntaxHighlighting}" />
```

C#:

```
public string syntaxHighlighting { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     syntaxHighlighting = "C#";
     DataContext = this;
}
```

But the Syntax Highlighting is not changed. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better solution for my problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go:

```
ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.TextEditor textEditor = new ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.TextEditor();
textEditor.ShowLineNumbers = true;
string dir = @"C:\Program Files\MyFolder\";
#if DEBUG
dir = @"C:\Dev\Sandbox\SharpDevelop-master\src\Libraries\AvalonEdit\ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit\Highlighting\Resources\";
#endif

Stream xshd_stream = File.OpenRead(dir + "CSharp-Mode.xshd");
XmlTextReader xshd_reader = new XmlTextReader(xshd_stream);
textEditor.SyntaxHighlighting = ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Highlighting.Xshd.HighlightingLoader.Load(xshd_reader, ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Highlighting.HighlightingManager.Instance);
xshd_reader.Close();
xshd_stream.Close();
```

**Edit:**

Since ICSharp.TextEditor throws AccessViolations in WinForms, I use AvalonEdit in WinForms:

```
ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
host.Size = new Size(200, 100);
host.Location = new Point(100, 100);
host.Child = textEditor;
this.Controls.Add(host);
```

Answer (score 35):

```
ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Highlighting.HighlightingManager.Instance.GetDefinition("C#");
```

Comment: `ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Highlighting.HighlightingManager.Instance.GetDefinitionByExtension(Path.GetExtension(FileName));`

Comment: Great answer. Never thought that it's hidden so deeeeeeeep, thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to bind to a string, you can define an IValueConverter to wrap the built in HighlightingDefinitionTypeConverter:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Highlighting;

public class HighlightingDefinitionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly HighlightingDefinitionTypeConverter Converter = new HighlightingDefinitionTypeConverter();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Converter.ConvertFrom(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Converter.ConvertToString(value);
    }
}
```

Then, just add the converter to your binding:

```
<avalonEdit:TextEditor Name="textEditor" SyntaxHighlighting="{Binding syntaxHighlighting, Converter={StaticResource HighlightingDefinitionConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Perfect for MVVM!

Answer (score 1):

Just use TypeConverter

```
var typeConverter = new HighlightingDefinitionTypeConverter();
var xmlSyntaxHighlighter = (IHighlightingDefinition)typeConverter.ConvertFrom("XML");
var csSyntaxHighlighter = (IHighlightingDefinition)typeConverter.ConvertFrom("C#");
CSharpEditor.SyntaxHighlighting = csSyntaxHighlighter;
XmlEditor.SyntaxHighlighting = xmlSyntaxHighlighter;
```

Answer (score 0):

syntaxHighlighting is not a string! your code might not compile! Note that SyntaxHighlighting in XAML here uses [markup extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322.aspx), which instantiates a instance of SyntaxHighlighting, not a string.

```
private void OnTabLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   textEditor.SyntaxHighlighting = HighlightingLoader.Load(..., HighlightingManager.Instance);
   textEditor.SyntaxHighlighting.MainRuleSet=...
}
```

Go to [sharpdevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) and download the source code.

Comment: Oh I see it, mh do you know how i can solve it? Can i change the Syntax when I have only the Name of it?

Comment: You'd better download SharpDevelop source and have a study on the source, it will help much.